# How do I use opencv with autohotkey?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, autohotkey

I couldn't find anything about using OpenCV with AutoHotkey on the internet.
Is there any way to use OpenCV in the ahk?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I am no expert in AutoHotKey, but I found some [resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EX0iT0NTTjw) that describe how to use AHK scripts within Java.  This is interesting because you can most definitely use openCV with Java.

I suspect that you can use Java to bridge the connection between openCV and AutoHotKey scripts, creating a final solution that uses openCV and AutoHotKey.

Hope that helps.